# Django rest framework + django-allauth

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, frameworks

I made a web application using python 3.6, django==1.11.5 and django-allauth==0.34.0 and would to add django-rest-framework + django-rest-auth, but there was problem, error about tzinfo. Is the django-rest-framework and django-allauth not compatible?

Answer (score 2):

yes, there are compatible.

you should take a look at:
https://github.com/wsvincent/drfx

it is a starter for django rest framework projects,
and it includes allauth.

Comment: this project is based uses django-rest which is end of life (not being developed or abandoned by the developers)

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi D Ambi It uses djangorestframework, django-rest-auth, and django-allauth and as far as I can tell those are all still live projects. What is django-rest, and why do you think this project is using it?